# How to modify the promql query to get sum of CPU usages of the all the pods belong to one service?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, cpu-usage, promql

How to modify the promql query to get the sum of all the pods (replicas) CPU usage belonging to one particular service?

To get the CPU usage of a single pod I use the following query :

```
rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="pod name",container="container name"}[5m]) by (container)
```

How can I modify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod="pod name",container="container name"}[5m])) by (container)` to get the sum of all the pods (replicas) CPU usage belonging to one particular service.